# What are these errors in starting bless in Ubuntu?

Tags: files, directory

Bless is the hex-editor which I start in Ubuntu 14.04. 
I think I installed `bless` by:

```
sudo apt-get install bless
```

There are some bug reports about such a behaviour but I am not sure if they are about the same thing. I do

```
bless binData.raw 
Directory '/home/masi/.config/bless/plugins' not found.
Directory '/home/masi/.config/bless/plugins' not found.
Directory '/home/masi/.config/bless/plugins' not found.
Could not find file "/home/masi/.config/bless/export_patterns".
```

How can you start bless correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a normal, I notice same output even bless is working fine.

Anyway if you want just to get rid of those warnings you can do this:

```
mkdir -p '/home/masi/.config/bless/plugins'
touch "/home/masi/.config/bless/export_patterns"
```

Now you can run `bless` without those output warnings, **But** as i told you above, i used it long time ago and works just fine even with those warnings